# AWS Athena working with nested arrays, trying to search for a field within the array

Tags: presto, amazon-athena

I have a sql query:

```
SELECT id_str, entities.hashtags
FROM tweets, unnest(entities.hashtags) as t(hashtag)
WHERE cardinality(entities.hashtags)=2  and id_str='1248585590573948928'
limit 5
```

which returns:

```
 id_str              hashtags
1248585590573948928 [{text=LUCAS, indices=[75, 81]}, {text=WayV, indices=[83, 88]}]
1248585590573948928 [{text=LUCAS, indices=[75, 81]}, {text=WayV, indices=[83, 88]}]
```

The unnesting has returned the row twice which originally was one row, this is because there are 2 objects in this array.
The next part I wanted to add to the sql query was

`select hashtag['text'] as htag` to the existing select which should return 2 rows still but this time returning `LUCAS` and `WayV` in the separate rows in same column, named `htag`.

But I get this error - any idea what I am doing wrong?

```
Your query has the following error(s):

SYNTAX_ERROR: line 1:8: '[]' cannot be applied to row(text varchar,indices array(bigint)), varchar(4)
```

I assume it is because I have another array within this array.. ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure where you're adding the `hashtag['text']` expression, so I can't say with confidence what your problem is, but I have two suggestions for you to try:

- The error says that `hashtag` is of type `row(text varchar, …)`, which suggests that `hashtag.text` should work.
- If that doesn't work, you can try using [`element_at`](https://prestosql.io/docs/0.172/functions/map.html) e.g. `element_at(hashtag, 'text')`.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this issue as well and since there is no solution provided I like to chip in:
After you unnest an array, you can address the result with a . reference instead of ['']:

```
WITH dataset AS (
  SELECT ARRAY[
    CAST(ROW('Bob', 38) AS ROW(name VARCHAR, age INTEGER)),
    CAST(ROW('Alice', 35) AS ROW(name VARCHAR, age INTEGER)),
    CAST(ROW('Jane', 27) AS ROW(name VARCHAR, age INTEGER))
  ] AS users
)

SELECT
user,
user.name
FROM dataset
cross join unnest (users) as t(user)
```